# Laravel 7 - Class 'Arr' not found

Tags: laravel

I did not know that the Arr class had stopped working in laravel 7 and I have the following query

```
$pagination = $request->query('pagination');
            $prod = Product::where('is_active', true)
                ->with(['categories', 'brand', 'images' => function ($query) {
                    $query->where('default', true);
                }])
                ->Order($request)
                ->BrandStore($request)
                ->CategoryStore($request, $active_categories)
                ->paginate(Arr::get($pagination, 'per_page', 5), ['*'], 'page', Arr::get($pagination, 'page', 1));
```

How could I change the Arr of the query?

```
->paginate(Arr::get($pagination, 'per_page', 60), ['*'], 'page', Arr::get($pagination, 'page', 1));
```

Comment: import it at the beginning of the file with `use Illuminate\Support\Arr;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the fully qualified name `\Illuminate\Support\Arr::` instead of `Arr::`:

```php
\Illuminate\Support\Arr::get($pagination, 'per_page', 60); //works
```

Or import it at the top of your file with the `use` statement:

```php
use \Illuminate\Support\Arr;

Arr::get($pagination, 'per_page', 60); //works
```